# How change base url in image tag?

Tags: asp.net-core, cdn, asp.net-core-middleware

I have many images in site. All images stay on site and use as static files. But I need change base url to cdn. I have middleware which verify images are exist. Then it reads image and write to context

```
// HttpContext contex;
byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(staticFilePath);
context.Response.ContentType = MimeKit.MimeTypes.GetMimeType(staticFilePath);
await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
```

I make download images from cdn but I think it isn`t good idea:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] fileContent = webClient.DownloadData(staticFilePath);
    context.Response.ContentType = MimeKit.MimeTypes.GetMimeType(staticFilePath);
    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe can I write url in ***context.Response.Body***?

Comment: Do you read the URL of the picture from the website, or do you have something similar to OSS storage and then directly obtain the URL to display the picture?

Comment: @Chaodeng, My images are static files and they kept in server. I use middleware where test exist this files and add in context.Response.Body